# Issue with rotating arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the font-awesome 4.7.0 css script in order to have an arrow next to a section. But, I don't really understand why doesn't it rotate down when the section is expanded.. Here is the HTML with the arrow:

```
            <h5 type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#L1">Example section <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right arrow"></i></h5>
            <div id="L1" class="collapse table-responsive table-striped">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" style="float:right">Export</button>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
```

Here is the CSS for the arrow as per my own thought:

```
#L1.arrow {
    transition: 0.5s all;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#L1.collapse .arrow {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

The transform does not work with CSS only ? Should there be a JS function for this ? If yes, could you please guide me ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `#L1.arrow {`

your first selector is looking for an element with id `L1` plus class of `arrow`.
those are two different elements in your html, so your selector never matches anything.

> `#L1.collapse .arrow {`

your second selector is looking for an element of class `arrow` and which is a child of (an element with id `L1` plus class of `collapse`).  this selector will never match either.

you probably don't need to specify `#L1` at all in your selectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. I went for the removal of #L1 from the css selector, however the arrow still does not rotate..

```
.arrow {
 transition: 0.5s all;
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.collapse .arrow {
 transition: all 0.5s;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```
Could this be due to the fact that the <i class is attached to an h5 element ?